# Retrofit 2.4.0 with Gradle plugin 3.1.2

Tags: android, gradle, retrofit2

I have a very simple question. I'm an Android Developer returning back to development after a 6 months break and as usual everything has changed apparently. Here is my question:

- Start a new Android project on Android Studio 3.1.2
- Default Gradle plugin is 3.1.2
- Added retrofit2 dependency to app's build.gradle

`implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'`

- Started gradle sync

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could
>   not resolve com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0. Open File Show
>   Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0. Open File Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0. Open File Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath':
>   Could not resolve com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0. Open File
>   Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0. Open File Show Details

I read the whole article about Gradle plugin 3 migration. It is no help.

Project build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xyz.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: show us your project and app level build.gradle files

Comment: I added the files you have asked for. There is really no complication at all. It's just a simple sample project and only one line of addition to the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

if your PC is running on some proxy please add proxy in android studio or check your internet connection.
For Proxy follow below steps:
File -> Settings -> Appearence & Behaviour -> System Setting -> HTTP Proxy
add your Proxy

Otherwise check your internet connection

Answer (score 0):

I run your code run with no errors. Try to Invalidate Caches/Restart from: File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart

Answer (score 0):

what worked me is to trying to add it through the project structure dependency window 
follow these steps : 
1- File -> Project structure -> depencies 
[image]

[image]

[image]

click apply then try to sync again and it worked fine for me.